# All pass filter design for group delay compensation

Tags: matlab, infinite-impulse-response, bandpass, group-delay, allpass

I've designed an IIR bandpass elliptic filter in Scilab with the following parameters.

1. Sampling Frequency = 25000 Hz
2. Lower cutoff frequency = 100 Hz
3. Upper cutoff frequency = 150 Hz
4. Pass band ripple = stop band ripple = 0.001 ~ 0.005 dB

The transfer function comes out to be

(-0.0006050 + 0.0024134z - 0.0030118z^2 + 1.075D-18z^3 + 0.0030118z^4 - 0.0024134z^5 + 0.0006050z^6) / (0.9600937 - 5.7967985z + 14.586174z^2 - 19.578664z^3 + 14.785532z^4 - 5.9563371z^5 + z^6)

I need to make the group delay in the pass-band, i.e. 100 Hz - 150 Hz for which I'm looking at using an IIR all pass filter. There a function in Matlab called [iirgrpdelay](https://in.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/iirgrpdelay.html) which accepts a vector of group delays corresponding to a range of frequencies between 2 frequency values (the pass band range) & generates an all-pass filter. The vector contains the delays needed for the frequency range in order to make it linear. An example for this can be found [here](http://spinlab.wpi.edu/courses/ece503_2014/7-2allpass_example.pdf).

This function isn't available in Scilab or Octave & I'm not sure how to design such an all pass filter which accepts a vector of the required group delays as input. What would be the technique used for this?

Comment: If you want linear phase, why don't you want to use an FIR filter?

Comment: Matt, 1st of all, am I glad to see your reply! I've been going through your thesis for a while now & I must say, it's exceptional! The reason why I can't use an FIR filter is that I need low group delay (1 - 2 cycles in the pass band frequency range) but my transition bandwidth is small as well (10 Hz). I've tried Windowed Sinc filters & the group delay is just too much for this. I only need linear phase in the small pass band (with respect to the sampling frequency) & felt that IIR would be the better option.

Comment: Here are links to my other questions, all related to the same topic - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49496/estimating-frequency-when-theres-little-isolation-between-signal-and-noise-freq ; https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49491/iir-filter-group-delay ; https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49303/interpolated-fir-filter-group-delay/49307?noredirect=1#comment96242_49307

Comment: Judging from your other questions, I don't think that you will be able to filter out the desired component with low group delay if the disturbance is so close in frequency. If I understand correctly, you have a spectral estimation problem, and you should also treat is as such.